# Error while updating to PHP 8 on Wordpress Custom Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, php-8, custom-theme

I'm doing a required update to PHP 8 on the WordPress custom theme.

The suggestion from WPEngine is: to change the theme back to the default one, disable all plugins, update to PHP 8, then switch back to the custom theme.

I tried the same steps but the result was a blank page (sometimes the page below), and the Console tab showed "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"
[image]

[image]

Does anyone have the experience to resolve this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update**: A few of error logs

PHP Warning:  Constant WP_POST_REVISIONS already defined in /nas/content/live/recession/wp-config.php on line 113

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pll_register_string() in /nas/content/live/recession/wp-content/themes/recession/functions.php:91

#10 /nas/content/live/recession/index.php(17): require('/nas/content/li...')

auditor:event=wp_login {"user_id":11,"blog_id":1,"event":"wp_login","current_user_id":0,"remote_addr":"90.13.800.12"}

Should I ignore errors from `live`? I believe it's the error while I attempted to preview the site.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message and the code involved. Maybe the code is not compatible with PHP8?

Comment: The code itself is the whole theme file with sub-folders in it. Not sure if I should check for all of the codes for deprecated functions/features?
The only error was this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ().

Comment: Open the error logs on the server and share what is being reported.

Comment: Look in your WPEngine dashboard at the error tab. The error log will tell you what's happening.

Comment: Thank you @user3783243, disinfor, I've updated my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes for some newbies (like myself) while updating the custom theme to PHP 8.0:

- If the custom theme breaks the whole webpage, you can check the `Error logs` tab (in WPEngine for example) and search for errors that start with `PHP Fatal Error`, which are most likely the causes that break your website.
- For instance, in my case, there's this error `Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + string`, which triggered the Fatal error message (It's because the previous dev has used `string + number`).
  All I need to do was to change it to `$var1 . (string)$var2` and it pretty much solved the issue.
- After fixing all the `Fatal Error`, the website was back online.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the image you sent indicated that something is messed up with the theme, usually "Fatal error". Maybe you can check which lines that caused this error in `WPEngine` perhaps?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33264737)